# Youtube DRM Movie videos are quality limited in Chrome on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: google-chrome, video, youtube, drm, quality

I have intalled recently Ubuntu 20.04 on my HP pavilion with AMD Ryzen 3.
I already installed the restricted extras and Google Chrome... now already i can watch all YouTube videos. The problem is when watching a Youtube movie that is DRM, the quality cant be higher than 480p as shown in the image below:
[screenshot of example how youtube dosent show higher options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BV3vp.png)

The quality options are limited i dont know why. I tried the same video in the same browser but in windows 10 and it has many more quality options (higher qualities like full hd).

This happens only in DRM videos.

Could you pleas help me with this, i dont know what to do.

Thanks for any help you can give me.